# How to parse wiki markdown in python using replace

Tags: python, replace

I'd like to use Python for deal with wikitext!

For example, original:

```
== 123 ==
=== 1234 ===
```

to:

```
<h2> 123 </h2>
<h3> 1234 </h3>
```

How to do that! Do I need a regex?
Will it work?

```
import re
block_head = r"""
(?P<head>
    ^
    \s*
    (?P<head_head> =+ )
    \s*
    (?P<head_text> .*? )
    \s*
    (?P=head_head)
    \s*
    $
  )
"""
while 1:
somestring=raw_input()
dict1=re.search(block_head,somestring, re.X).groupdict()
if(dict1['head_head']=='======'):
    print '<h6>'+dict1['head_text']+'</h6>'
if(dict1['head_head']=='====='):
    print '<h5>'+dict1['head_text']+'</h5>'
if(dict1['head_head']=='===='):
    print '<h4>'+dict1['head_text']+'</h4>'
```

And I wonder how to solve this problem:

```
abc'''123'''aa
```

to

```
abc<b>123</b>aa
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you interested in regex or are you in need of a general wikimedia parser in python.  If the latter, many exist:  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: Thank you.But most of them cannot deal with complicated text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably want to go with regular expressions.

You may want to avoid reinventing the wheel though. The [MoinMoin python wiki platform](http://moinmo.in) already implements various format handlers, including a [Media Wiki format](https://bitbucket.org/thomaswaldmann/moin-2.0/src/tip/MoinMoin/converter/mediawiki_in.py) handler that indeed uses regular expressions to parse the input text.

To borrow from that implementation, it uses the regular expression:

```
block_head = r"""
    (?P<head>
        ^
        \s*
        (?P<head_head> =+ )
        \s*
        (?P<head_text> .*? )
        \s*
        (?P=head_head)
        \s*
        $
    )
"""
```

to match a line with 1 or more `=` characters, followed by text, followed by the same number of `=` characters. This uses the verbose regex syntax with the `re.X` flag (where whitespace is ignored).

Using that regular expression you can match headers and figure out their 'level' by counting the number of `=` characters:

```
>>> re.search(block_head, '=== Some header! ===', re.X).groupdict()
{'head_text': 'Some header!', 'head': '=== Some header! ===', 'head_head': '==='}
```

A non-verbose version would be:

```
block_head = r"(?P<head>^\s*(?P<head_head>=+)\s*(?P<head_text>.*?)\s*(?P=head_head)\s*$)"
```

Use that as a starting point (read the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) carefully until you understand what each part does), then expand from there.

Comment: Thank you! But I want to write a simple one by myself and lean how to use replace and regex

Comment: Can you give me an example more detail! Thank you!

Comment: If this is an educational exercise as you suggest, then take a look at the [Dive Into Python](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/regular-expressions.html) guide to regular expressions.

Comment: But how about === 123 === 456 == 34 ==
It should be <h3> 123 </h3> 456 <h2> 34 </h2>

Comment: @caizixian: No, not in MediaWiki that doesn't. Headers are meant to be block-level items, one per line.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Got it!

Comment: Can I first deal with the ======123======
then =====213=====....==123==
Is that OK?

Comment: Try it out; the regular expression in my answer matches that.

Comment: I'm going to go to write Wikioffline Reader.But all the pages were stored in Wikitext. I have no idea!

Comment: Most of all, try to *first* understand what the regular expression *does*, so that you can then adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Markdown in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) module over at PyPi as a reference while you're trying to implement your own. Run `sudo pip install markdown` then navigate to your Python install directory`/lib/python.version/site-packages/markdown` for the built and installed package, or you can just download the archive from the link above and browse through the original source. There's a lot there, but you should be able to find some good examples of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

reg = re.compile('^(={1,3})(.+?)\\1 *\r?$',re.MULTILINE)

s = '''== B123 ==
=== Z1234 ==='''

def ripl(m, d = {'=':'h1','==':'h2','===':'h3'}):
    return '<{0:s}>{1:s}</{0:s}>'.format(d[m.group(1)],m.group(2))

print reg.sub(ripl,s)
```

Explanation of the regex's pattern:

`^` without `re.MULTILINE` flag would means 'start of the string'.
`^` with `re.MULTILINE` means 'start of a line or of the string'.

`(={1,3})` is a capturing group, the group 1.
It catches 1 to 3 characters **=** , but since the group is preceded by `^` , it catches these **=** only at the start of a line.

`(.+?)` is the capturing group number 2.
`.+?` catches all kind of characters (except **\n** , 'cause the dot without re.DOTALL flag doesn't match **\n** )
If it was `(.+)` only , it would be greedy, that is to say it would go as far it could: well, in the present case, as the dot doesn't match **\n** , it would go until the end of line, that is until the position in front of **\n** and the second group would catch the second series **=** or **==** or **===** too, what we don't want.
But the `?` after `.+` enjoins this expression `.+` to be ungreedy, that is to say to stop somewhere as soon as it will bump into what is specified after `.+?`

So, `\\1 *\r?$` defines the group of characters in front of which `.+?` will stop. The parenthesis `)` between `.+?` and `\\1 *\r?$` doesn't matter from this point of view.
It means :

- 1) the same group of character as in front of the line, which must be catched by group 1, that's represented by `\\1`
- 2) then possibly a series of blanks (useless but there may be some at this place)
- 3) then possibly **\r** , but not mandatory. I put this because on Windows the end of lines are with **\r\n**
- 4) at last, `$` means 'end of a line or of the string' because re.MULTILINE changes its meaning the same as for `^`

I put this condition `\\1 *\r?$` to assert that the series **=** or **==** or **===** that will match will be the last. For, the part `.+?` is said to stop at the first one it will encouter. And what, when the first isn't the last ? For this case, we must ordain to `.+?` to stop in front of the same as group 1 only if this same one is situated at the end of the line: so this lets the possibility for charachters **=** to  be present in the line (in fact I don't know if it is possible in the wiki, but I thought about this case)

.

NB
To exclude cases in which

```
===abcd=====
======ijk==
```

are transformed into

```
<h3>abcd==</h3>
<h2>====ijk</h2>
```

the pattern must be `'^(={1,3}(?!=))(.+?)(?<!=)\\1 *\r?$'`

The part `(?!=)` means 'just after this position in the string where the succession of 1 to 3 characters **=** stops, there must be absence of another **=**'

The part `(?<!=)` means 'just in front of this position in the string where the last succession of 1 to 3 characters **=** begins, there must be absence of another **=**'